# What does "help them" actually refer to?

Tags: ingress

In the Recruiter Badge description, it says "Recruit new agents into Ingress and *help them*". What does "help them" mean?

- Does it count as "helping" when my recruits click on the invitation email?
- Am I supposed to give them items?
- Am I supposed to help them get to a higher level?
- Is it a must for both me and my recruit to be on the same Faction?
- Do I need to help my recruits within a certain time frame else it does not count?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're supposed to get them to a higher level. (L3, to be exact).

The recruit may choose the opposing faction. I don't know if you get points for them if they do that. "Helping them" is not a particularly good idea in that case …

Answer (score 1):

Help them any way you can. Help them to evolve, give them staffs, tell them, what will be the next event, how can earn a badge, how to ask the local community, teach them to glyph.

Once, you choosed your fraction, you have responsibility for your team.  (I hope that is the ENL :)

Show them the missions, tell them about banners, mission day, anomalies, back story, everything what you know about the game.

Thats all. Just help them.